# What are the best technique and algorithms to detect and recognize text in a image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, text-recognition

I am newbie in text detection ans recognition, but I am confused about how to detect and recognize correctly a text in a image, I founded tessarec but it don't gave me a good result, I used it in a Gui java's Swing's screenshot, what i want to do is to implement my own program, but i need some advice to do that

I want use OpenCv and Python for that

Thanks,

Comment: It is hard to beat tesseract (python bindings via pytesseract). I think you should try different ways to preprocess your images and play around with the tesseract config files before you try to roll your own.

Comment: I don't mind if my program will be better or not than tessarct, but i just want to learn the algorithms to detect text, I want t understad the methodology and the differents ways to detect and recognize the text in a images

Comment: for detecting possible text areas, there was a method, something with "stroke width" or sth...

Answer (score -1):

use **google cloud api for computer vision** it just detect your text in image and convert it it to text and send back to you json file so you can use that in your project its easiest one and if you want to use in opencv use

> OCRTesseract class

and check out this link for text recognition with opencv Python

http://www.danvk.org/2015/01/07/finding-blocks-of-text-in-an-image-using-python-opencv-and-numpy.html